SPSS PROCESS moderation cluster standard errors syntax
I want to conduct a moderation in SPSS PROCESS macro:
IV: Personality trait (measured on likert scale - not repeated measure but constant)
Moderator: low trust vs high trust
DV: initial price offer in a negotiation (values can be between 5-15 - repeated measures within subjects)
I would like to account for my within subjects design by using the syntax.
I didnt succeed writing the code yet for the standard errors, but i have this for the moderation:
*testing p r o c e s s model 1.
process y=offer /x=Agree /w=Time / cov=Neuro Open Consc Trust Extro Age Gender /model=1.
How can I add a code to cluster standard errors and account for the within subjects design?
